# Не подхватывает value из select option JS

Tags: javascript, select

Здравствуйте. 
Не пойму где беда, но значение value(или text, тоже пробовал) не подхватывается в функции. Подскажите где я тут туплю. 
Спасибо!

```js
let hour1 = document.querySelector('#my_time_hour1');
let min1 = document.querySelector('#my_time_min1');
let hour2 = document.querySelector('#my_time_hour2');
let min2 = document.querySelector('#my_time_min2');
let hour1Val = hour1.options[hour1.selectedIndex].value;
let min1Val = min1.options[min1.selectedIndex].value;
let hour2Val = hour2.options[hour2.selectedIndex].value;
let min2Val = min2.options[min2.selectedIndex].value;


function goKuku() {
  if (hour1Val > hour2Val) {
    alert(hour1Val);
    alert(hour1Va2)
  } else if (min1 > min2) {
    alert(min1);
    alert(min2);
  } else {
    alert("ne kuku");
  }
}
hour1.onchange = function() {
  goKuku();
}
min1.onchange = function() {
  goKuku();
}
hour2.onchange = function() {
  goKuku();
}
min2.onchange = function() {
  goKuku();
}
```

```html
<select id="my_time_hour2">
  <option value="00">00</option>
  <option value="01">01</option>
  <option value="02">02</option>
  <option value="03">03</option>
  <option value="04">04</option>
  <option value="05">05</option>
  <option value="06">06</option>
  <option value="07">07</option>
  <option value="08">08</option>
  <option value="09">09</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="11">11</option>
  <option selected value="12">12</option>
  <option value="13">13</option>
  <option value="14">14</option>
  <option value="15">15</option>
  <option value="16">16</option>
  <option value="17">17</option>
  <option value="18">18</option>
  <option value="19">19</option>
  <option value="20">20</option>
  <option value="21">21</option>
  <option value="22">22</option>
  <option value="23">23</option>
</select>
<select id="my_time_min2">
  <option value="00">00</option>
  <option value="15">15</option>
  <option value="30">30</option>
  <option value="45">45</option>
</select>
<select id="my_time_hour1">
  <option value="00">00</option>
  <option value="01">01</option>
  <option value="02">02</option>
  <option value="03">03</option>
  <option value="04">04</option>
  <option value="05">05</option>
  <option value="06">06</option>
  <option value="07">07</option>
  <option value="08">08</option>
  <option value="09">09</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="11">11</option>
  <option selected value="12">12</option>
  <option value="13">13</option>
  <option value="14">14</option>
  <option value="15">15</option>
  <option value="16">16</option>
  <option value="17">17</option>
  <option value="18">18</option>
  <option value="19">19</option>
  <option value="20">20</option>
  <option value="21">21</option>
  <option value="22">22</option>
  <option value="23">23</option>
</select>
<select id="my_time_min1">
  <option value="00">00</option>
  <option value="15">15</option>
  <option value="30">30</option>
  <option value="45">45</option>
</select>
```

Вот ссылка на скрипку так же http://jsfiddle.net/s65n9b3z/65/

Comment: как минимум ты сравниваешь строки, а не числа........... в min1 и min2 вообще даже не значения лежат....... ну и в целом значения у тебя заполняются только однажды при загрузке страницы, а не при каждом событии onchange

Comment: @АлексейШиманский преобразовал таким образом-   Number(hour1Val);(так можно вообще?) ,но ничего не поменялось. Почему minN ничего не возвращает? Почему однажды, если есть onchange?

Comment: `+hour1.options[hour1.selectedIndex].value;` - вот так можно. с плюсиком в начале, чтоб в число конвертировать..........`ничего не поменялось.` - потому что я описал целых **ТРИ** проблемы, которые нужно решить........ `Почему minN ничего не возвращает?` - это я вообще не понял..........`Почему однажды, если есть onchange?` - onchange это событие которое вызывается, когда выбираешь другое значение в option....... всё. точка! Просто триггер. Но чтобы взять при этом текущее значение, нужно в этом событии написать это самое взятие значение. А ты их написал в самом начале, а не в обработчике

Comment: @АлексейШиманский [Почему minN ничего не возвращает? - это я вообще не понял] подскажите, если знаете куда копать. [Просто триггер.] то есть в вызываемой функции нужно снова вызывать value? о_О

Comment: `есть в вызываемой функции нужно снова вызывать value?` - ну как бы да. Непонятно почему ты ожидал другого. Ведь в обработчиках можно написать любую логику, хоть на миллион строк, и то, что onchange должен был откуда-то догадаться брать аж целых четыре значения из select'ов - как-то странно

Comment: @АлексейШиманский спасибо, советы помогли.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var selects = document.querySelectorAll('select');

for (var i = 0; i < selects.length; i++) {
    selects[i].addEventListener('change', function(event) {
        goKuku();
    });
}


function goKuku() {
    let hour1 = document.querySelector('#my_time_hour1');
    let min1 = document.querySelector('#my_time_min1');
    let hour2 = document.querySelector('#my_time_hour2');
    let min2 = document.querySelector('#my_time_min2');
    let hour1Val = +hour1.options[hour1.selectedIndex].value;
    let min1Val = +min1.options[min1.selectedIndex].value;
    let hour2Val = +hour2.options[hour2.selectedIndex].value;
    let min2Val = +min2.options[min2.selectedIndex].value;

    if (hour1Val > hour2Val) {
        console.log('hour1Val: ', hour1Val);
        console.log('hour2Val: ', hour2Val);
    } else if (min1 > min2) {
        console.log('min1Val: ', min1Val);
        console.log('min2Val: ', min2Val);
    } else {
        console.log('ne kuku');
    }
}
```

```html
<select id="my_time_hour2">
    <option value="00">00</option>
    <option value="01">01</option>
    <option value="02">02</option>
    <option value="03">03</option>
    <option value="04">04</option>
    <option value="05">05</option>
    <option value="06">06</option>
    <option value="07">07</option>
    <option value="08">08</option>
    <option value="09">09</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option selected value="12">12</option>
    <option value="13">13</option>
    <option value="14">14</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="16">16</option>
    <option value="17">17</option>
    <option value="18">18</option>
    <option value="19">19</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="21">21</option>
    <option value="22">22</option>
    <option value="23">23</option>
</select>
<select id="my_time_min2">
    <option value="00">00</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
    <option value="45">45</option>
</select>
<select id="my_time_hour1">
    <option value="00">00</option>
    <option value="01">01</option>
    <option value="02">02</option>
    <option value="03">03</option>
    <option value="04">04</option>
    <option value="05">05</option>
    <option value="06">06</option>
    <option value="07">07</option>
    <option value="08">08</option>
    <option value="09">09</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option selected value="12">12</option>
    <option value="13">13</option>
    <option value="14">14</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="16">16</option>
    <option value="17">17</option>
    <option value="18">18</option>
    <option value="19">19</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="21">21</option>
    <option value="22">22</option>
    <option value="23">23</option>
</select>
<select id="my_time_min1">
    <option value="00">00</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
    <option value="45">45</option>
</select>
```